# Doing a batch delete in redis with ohm

Tags: ruby, redis, ohm

Is there a way to delete multiple objects in redis via the ruby gem ohm? Right now to delete multiple data we do a loop and call object.delete each one of them. I would appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this with Ohm directly, but you can [drop down to the base redis gem](http://redis.io/commands/del) and do it that way as Redis supports multiple keys with the [delete command](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/Ohm.html#redis-class_method).

So, something like this:

```
Model.redis.delete *records.map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try,

```
Model.all.map &:delete
```

Though it may not be the best solution because it also loops through all objects, but it works or me.